# How to connect to db2 database if we are provided with DB2 ODBC connection via System DSN?

Tags: database, db2, database-connection

DB2 database connection details are provided as ODBC registry file. The file is imported and the connection details are stored under System DSN.

Now by using which GUI tool one can connect to the DB2 database and we are provided with only ODBC connection details.

Answer (score 0):

you need to download and install IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI

from: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/download-initial-version-115-clients-and-drivers